# How to use Google Sheets script to open a modal form on open event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It only works if I call the modal by pressing from the custom menu, but if I put it in the event when opening it does not load it, but if it creates the menu that's why I don't know why it doesn't load the modal

```js
const spreadsheetId = 'your spreedsheet id';

function addMenuItem() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('My Functions')
  .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showModal')
  .addToUi();
}

function showModal() {
  const userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My modal');
}

function inputData(data) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([data]);
}

function onOpen(e){
  addMenuItem();
  showModal();  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, and Welcome!</h1>
    <input id='my_input' placeholder='Insert your Data'><br>
    <button id='my_button'>Submit</button>
    
    <script>
      document.getElementById('my_button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
      
        const data = document.getElementById('my_input').value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(displaySuccess)
        .inputData(data);
        
      });
      
      function displaySuccess() {
        google.script.host.close();
      }             
});


</script>        
  </body>      
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a little hint: Java is not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[Simple Triggers Restrictions:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

- You are using HTML Service therefore you need to use [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) since they can call services that require authorization. I tried adding onOpen() as a installable trigger and when I open the file, the modal was shown successfully.

**There are 2 ways on how to create an installable trigger:**

**1. [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)**

- Open your Apps Script project.
- click Triggers alarm.
- At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
- Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
- Click Save.

Sample Configuration:

[image]

**2. [Managing triggers programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)**

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet opens.
 */
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```